# Builder pattern in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns

I'm used to construct object using the builder pattern like the following:

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject.Builder()
    .setProperty1(property1)
    .setProperty2(property2)
    .setProperty3(property3)
    .create();
```

I'm new to **Objective-C** specifically iOS, and I am wondering not exactly it, but if this design pattern is actually used (since you need nested classes, static methods, etc). If there is an *equivalent* design pattern, I'd like to learn it, or if it is used exactly as it is, I'd like an example.

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest you to read the following article : https://annema.me/2014/04/04/the-builder-pattern-in-objective-c/

Comment: 404's now :( Any chance you could post an example in your answer of the recommended way to implement a builder pattern?

Comment: @stevendesu Well I'm not sure that showing how to use pattern in Objective-C would be useful now...

Comment: If your reason is that Objective-C is dead in favor of Swift, I've got some bad news for you: businesses move slow. My company has a requirement to use Objective-C for a client SDK at the moment. Of particular interest to me regarding the Builder pattern in Objective-C (versus other OO languages): 1. Should you use a class method which allocates an instance from a builder, or should you use an object method to configure a pre-allocated instance? 2. Does Objective-C have any concept of "internal classes" like Java does, allowing you to say `MyClass.Builder`?